# EhCache distrubuted peers config (through RMI)

Tags: distributed, ehcache

Assume I've 2 nodes in cluser A, B confugured through manual discovery.

May I use `same` configuration file for both nodes, or I should exclude node A from node A config (rmiUrls list), and node B from node B config (rmiUrls list)?

```
<!-- For RMI replication (Setting the peer provider factory) -->
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="peerDiscovery=manual, rmiUrls=//A_IP:40000/MyCache|//B_IP:40000/MyCache"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory should be configured with other node and other nodes's port, whereas cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory should be configured with local node and local port.